# Model View Matrix from Quaterion

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, game-engine, game-physics

I have my objects in a game engine described by two objects:
a position vector: (x, y, z); and 
a rotation quaternion: (w, a, b, c)

I am now looking for the maths I need to build my model view matrix, I have a mathematics rather than programming background so the tutorials I have found reference functions, and I'd rather have a better understanding of the raw calculations.

It is being built in Java, with opengl as a rendering engine

As an aside, does anyone know  of  a  method in java for setting the model matrix? Ie:

Float [3][3] matrix = new matrix;
ModelMatrix.set (matrix)

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use, with `q` being the Quaternion:

```
matrix = new float[3][3];
float x2 = q.x*q.x, y2 = q.y*q.y, z2 = q.z*q.z;
matrix[0][0] = (1-2*z2-2*y2); 
matrix[0][1] = (2*q.x*q.y+2*q.w*q.z); 
matrix[0][2] = (2*q.x*q.z-2*q.w*q.y);
matrix[1][0] = (2*q.x*q.y-2*q.w*q.z); 
matrix[1][1] = (1-2*z2-2*x2); 
matrix[1][2] = (2*q.y*q.z+2*q.w*q.x);
matrix[2][0] = (2*q.x*q.z+2*q.w*q.y); 
matrix[2][1] = (2*q.y*q.z-2*q.w*q.x); 
matrix[2][2] = (1-2*y2-2*x2);
```

Comment: I was under the impression  it was a 4x4 matrix

Comment: In this case, it doesn't really matter. Since a quaternion only describes a rotation, the rest of the matrix is set to 0 except of the [3][3] element, which is 1.

Comment: you can replace the 1 with the lengthSquared so it can work with quaternions that also have scale.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the method from [jMonkeyEngine's Quaternion class](https://github.com/jMonkeyEngine/jmonkeyengine/blob/e2d8fe829359dd6028d6810efddbf671d9980231/jme3-core/src/main/java/com/jme3/math/Quaternion.java)
It's for a 4x4 matrix structured in a float[16].

```
public float[] toRotationMatrix(float[] result) {

        float norm = norm();
        // we explicitly test norm against one here, saving a division
        // at the cost of a test and branch.  Is it worth it?
        float s = (norm == 1f) ? 2f : (norm > 0f) ? 2f / norm : 0;

        // compute xs/ys/zs first to save 6 multiplications, since xs/ys/zs
        // will be used 2-4 times each.
        float xs = x * s;
        float ys = y * s;
        float zs = z * s;
        float xx = x * xs;
        float xy = x * ys;
        float xz = x * zs;
        float xw = w * xs;
        float yy = y * ys;
        float yz = y * zs;
        float yw = w * ys;
        float zz = z * zs;
        float zw = w * zs;

        // using s=2/norm (instead of 1/norm) saves 9 multiplications by 2 here
        result[0] = 1 - (yy + zz);
        result[1] = (xy - zw);
        result[2] = (xz + yw);
        result[4] = (xy + zw);
        result[5] = 1 - (xx + zz);
        result[6] = (yz - xw);
        result[8] = (xz - yw);
        result[9] = (yz + xw);
        result[10] = 1 - (xx + yy);

        return result;
    }
```

Since you're asking for the whole model matrix: 
Translation occupies position 3, 7 , 11 in the same matrix. 
Edit: A lookup showed i was wrong about the scale.

Comment: This assumes, that result is previously initialized with an identity matrix. Otherwise all not set values are undefined.